# parallelize gaussian algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, gaussian

I want to parallelize this kind of gaussian algorithm. I cant find any solution to share the calculations in the loops with other processes. Is there a chance to parallelize the whole code or code fragments?

```
for k=1:n-1
for i=k+1:n
    M(i,k) = M(i,k) / M(k,k);
    a(i) = a(i) - a(k)*M(i,k);
    for j=k+1:n
        M(i,j) = M(i,j) - M(k,j)*M(i,k);
    end
end end
```

At first, this is a theoretical problem. After I have a solution, I want to program this code with OpenMPI.

Thanks a lot!
John

Comment: Googled "gaussian algorithm matrix parallel algorithm" and found lots of hits.

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian elimination is indeed a strongly sequential process. You can't choose a pivot element before you have finished the previous elimination step. Eliminations can be parallelized by assigning a stretch of rows to the processing units, but the fraction of the array to be updated goes diminishing (qudratically).

Another approach could be by block decomposition, assigning the blocks to the processing units in a farming mode. Here again, will be hard to keep all PU's busy.

Comment: Thank you. This algorithm is without choosing a pivot element. My plan is to divide a loop to several processes. But I can't find a solution. In my opinion, each loop uses a value of the previous step.